# Using strstr() function with pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

Hello to everyone who is  spending the new year night in front of a computer.

I have a struct definition like that:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
 char *charName;
 char *List;
} example;

example oneStruct;
```

then in somewhere in code I have a line like that:

```
if (strstr (oneStruct.list, theWord) != NULL)
  ...
```

when I debug it, the program crashes right here in this line.

'oneStruct.list' is empty now, as I am going to add some elements depending on this if situation.

****PROGRESSS

I managed to make it to the next phase, so I am adding the "theWord" string to the 'oneStruct.list'

```
 strcat (oneStruct.list, theword);
```

and I face with the same problem.

the compiler gives no errors, but when I run the program it stoppes working in Windows, and gives a "segmentation fault" on ubuntu.

I have included the string.h but I get problems about string.h functions. Can't I use those functions with a pointer in a struct?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is one of your pointers NULL (or otherwise invalid)?  What did the debugger say?

Comment: Why the first line? It seems that you are insulting us! o___O

Comment: I haven't done any process with oneStruct.list yet. just the initialization

Comment: "the program crushes" - so it falls in love with another process? The word you are looking for is "crashes".

Comment: sorry @haccks but I really couldn't understand what is the insulting part here?

Comment: sorry for bad english buddy. edited.

Comment: @user3108849: "Hello to everyone who is spending the new year night in front of a computer." makes it sound like we have no friends. Or, for those of us that do have friends and will be spending new years night with them (it's still day time here), it seems like you're not saying hello to us.

Comment: well I'm a European so I forgot the situation of the Americans :) it's almost new year here. SOORRRYY :)

Comment: added progress to the question. please check it guys

Comment: what do you mean "post your code" ? this is where the problem is.

Comment: We need your code to see how you set `oneStruct.list`. The new `strcat (oneStruct.list, theword)` has a code smell, and is possibly (or likely!) incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that `example.list` is empty. That probably means that the pointer `.list` has not been initialized - it might be NULL, it might be pointing to memory halfway to Jupiter.

Make sure your pointers are initialized - to NULL until you want to use them, to something sensible after. Then, test for NULL before using them. So

```
if(example.list != NULL && theWord != NULL) {
  if(strstr(example.list, theWord) != NULL) {
     ..etc
```

Happy New Year.

**UPDATE** to do a `strcat`, you again need valid pointers. So you need to make sure that the place where you want to add your string has enough space allocated already.  You might consider doing something like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // -- need this to make sure the malloc prototype is known
#include <string.h>   //  -- and this to make sure strcat prototype is known

char* safecat(char *s1, char *s2) {
  if(s1 == NULL) {
    s1 = malloc(strlen(s2) + 1);
  }
  strcat(s1, s2);
  return s1;
}
```

This will make sure that if you pass a NULL as the first pointer, it will be updated to have the length of the second string. You could make it more fancy, and do

```
char* safecat(char *s1, char *s2) {
  if(s1 == NULL) {
    s1 = malloc(strlen(s2) + 1);
  }
  else {
    s1 = realloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
  }
  strcat(s1, s2);
  return s1;
}
```

which would make sure you have enough space for `s1` plus `s2`. But the risk is that you will become a sloppy programmer (and there are all kinds of ways in which this code is not "right").

## Key point:

You, as the programmer, are responsible for making sure that you pass valid pointers to your functions, and that there is enough space for copy / concatenate / etc operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my program with this and I managed to get into the next phase. Editing the question to show progress, please check it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, detailed explanation and advices :) Happy new year!

Comment: Your safecat isn't safe :)  strcat assumes that its first argument points to an actual string that it can find the end of to know where to start appending.  A freshly malloced chunk of memory doesn't satisfy this and strcat may, as you put it, head off halfway to Jupiter looking for a '/0' that isn't there.

Comment: @nigelharper - I realize that... It's why I said "all kinds of ways this code is not right". But if you start with null pointers I hope it will at least help a little...

Comment: err.. what if I use calloc?

Comment: That would make make sure the memory is filled with zeros, so be a bit safer if you did it before the call to `safecat`. Or set the pointer to NULL and have `safecat` do the allocating. Key is to make sure that you "own" all the memory you might run into. Look at things like `strncat` - they have a "no more than n" argument. Defensive coding is a good habit.

Comment: I will definitely try something like that because there are some random characters in the list before the word I added. apart from that, does this safecat function copies the "\0" character which is at the end of the word?

Comment: Look at the code - it uses `strcat` after checking some "obvious" problems (like `s1 == NULL`). It is by no means "The Solution", just a friendly pointer (pun intended). Always keep the **key point** at the end of the post in mind...

Comment: what is the key point? I couldn't understand you. I don't have a good English